# Perform dataframe join before another one

Tags: python, pyspark

What would be nice and fast way to perform a dataframe `join` between 3 tables?
Also I need to have duplicate columns in my dataframe.

```
   SELECT
      tbl_1.id,
      tbl_2.id,
      tbl_3.id 
    FROM tbl_1
    JOIN tbl_2
      ON tbl_1.id = tbl_2.id 
    JOIN tbl_3
      ON tbl_3.id = tbl_2.id ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing: if you want to have all duplicated columns in the output DataFrame, you should prefix them with something, so that they can be differentiated somehow. Example:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2), (1, 1)], "id: int, val: int")
df.show()
+---+---+
| id|val|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  1|  1|
+---+---+

from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df.select([col(c).alias("df1_" + c) for c in df.columns]).show()
+------+-------+
|df1_id|df1_val|
+------+-------+
|     1|      2|
|     1|      1|
+------+-------+
```

Second thing: if the SQL syntax is not available for any reason, then you will have to join the DataFrames one by one - the `join` method takes only one DataFrame as right side of join, so you can chain them for example. Snippet:

```py
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 1), (1, 4)], "df1_id: int, df1_val: int")
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2), (1, 5)], "df2_id: int, df2_val: int")
df3 = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 3), (1, 6)], "df3_id: int, df3_val: int")

df1.join(df2, df1.df1_id == df2.df2_id, "inner").join(df3, df1.df1_id == df3.df3_id, "inner").show()
+------+-------+------+-------+------+-------+
|df1_id|df1_val|df2_id|df2_val|df3_id|df3_val|
+------+-------+------+-------+------+-------+
|     1|      4|     1|      5|     1|      3|
|     1|      4|     1|      2|     1|      3|
|     1|      1|     1|      5|     1|      3|
|     1|      1|     1|      2|     1|      3|
|     1|      4|     1|      5|     1|      6|
|     1|      4|     1|      2|     1|      6|
|     1|      1|     1|      5|     1|      6|
|     1|      1|     1|      2|     1|      6|
+------+-------+------+-------+------+-------+
```